# How to add OnClicked event for StaticMeshComponent in ure4.7?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Hej, I've been trying to click on StaticMeshComponent during Run-time, but not able to click on particular StaticMeshComponent. I've tried the below logic to click and set the material inside OnClick() Function, but not able succeed. Is AddDynamic approach correct ??
In .cpp

```
    StaticMeshComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("StaticMeshComponentCOMP"));
    ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UStaticMesh> StaticMesh_obj(TEXT("/Game/StarterContent/Meshs/Chairs_Chair1"));
    StaticMeshComponent->SetStaticMesh(StaticMesh_obj.Object);
    StaticMeshComponent->OnClicked.AddDynamic(this, &AMyActor::OnClick);
    StaticMeshComponent->AttachTo(RootComponent);

// OnClick Function


 void AMyActor::OnClick(UPrimitiveComponent* pComponent)
     {
ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UMaterial> MeshMaterial(TEXT("/Game/GTFreeMaterials/Materials/Metal_BrushedSteel"));

        // Set properties for Staic mesh component
        StaticMeshComponentArray[i]->SetMaterial(0, MeshMaterial.Object);
         FMessageDialog::Open(EAppMsgType::Ok, FText::FromString(TEXT("Clicked")));
     }
```

In .h

```
 void OnClick(UPrimitiveComponent* pComponent);
```

Could you guys please help me in this issues Or guide me any another efficient logic to solve my problem.

P.S: Game Mode : Mouse Click mode

Answer (score 3):

I just put together a quick test and everything worked correctly. Perhaps the steps I used will help you:

1，Launch UE4.18; Create a new C++ project with Basic Code, Desktop/Console, Maximum Quality, and No Starter Content

2，Add a Player Controller C++ class and use the default constructor so show the mouse cursor, and enable click and mouse-over events

3，Open the C++ Game Mode class that was generated with the project and use the default constructor to set the default Player Controller class to my new class

4，Edit the Project Settings to use the C++ Game Mode class (Maps & Modes -> Default Modes -> Default GameMode)

5，Add a new Pawn C++ class with a click function that simply logs a message to the output log and registers that function in the default constructor

6，Add a blueprint class derived from my C++ Pawn class and add a **Cube(Static Mesh Component)** to its components, then **check "Hidden in Game"** in it's Detail Panel.
Or
If want to use Character’s default CollisionProfile `Pawn` to receive `Clicked Event`, `Visibility` must to be set as `Block`( Project Settings -> Engine -> Collision -> Preset -> Pawn -> Trace Type -> Visibility).

[image]

A strict way is to add new `Trace Channel` for Click testing, see more details on this video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yo9VrxFgUJY

7，Place one of my blueprint Pawns into the scene in front of the player

8，Play the level, click the cube of my blueprint Pawn class, view the Output Log and see that the message appeared

**Major code:**

in AMyCharacter Constructor

```
OnClicked.AddUniqueDynamic(this, &AMyCharacter::OnSelected);
```

in header AMyCharacter.h

```
UFUNCTION()
        void OnSelected(AActor* Target, FKey ButtonPressed);
```

in AMyCharacter.cpp

```
void AMyCharacter ::OnSelected(AActor* Target, FKey ButtonPressed)
{
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 2.f, FColor::Cyan, FString("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"));
}
```